# Array not resetting when input changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to populate select box using value from input text. So far I've been doing good in populating the select box. But the problems came when I change the input field into another value. The select box won't reset the array instead of adding the option value in the end of array. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="ttc_list" id="ttc_list" />
<select name="priority_list" id="priority_list">
    <option value="">Choose TTC First...</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#priority_list").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('input[name="ttc_list"]').change(function() {
        var arr = [];
        arr.length = 0;
        var ttc = $("#ttc_list").val();

        if(ttc == 100 || ttc == 101)
        {
            var prty100_Start = 40;
            var prty100_End = 80;
                while(prty100_Start < prty100_End+1){
                  arr.push(zeroPad(prty100_Start++,2));
                }
        }
        else
        {
            var prty200_Start = 1;
            var prty200_End = 5;
                while(prty200_Start < prty200_End+1){
                  arr.push(zeroPad(prty200_Start++,2));
                }
        }

        var selectOptions = {
           100: arr,
           101: arr,
           200: arr,
           204: arr,
           210: arr
        }

        $("select#priority_list").removeAttr("disabled");
        console.log($(this).val());
        if(selectOptions[$(this).val()]) 
        {
            console.log(selectOptions[$(this).val()]);
               $.each(selectOptions[$(this).val()], function() { 
                   $('select[name="priority_list"]').append('<option>' + this + '</option>'); 
               });
        }
    });
});

function zeroPad(num, numZeros) {
    var n = Math.abs(num);
    var zeros = Math.max(0, numZeros - Math.floor(n).toString().length );
    var zeroString = Math.pow(10,zeros).toString().substr(1);
    if( num < 0 ) {
        zeroString = '-' + zeroString;
    }
    return zeroString+n;
}
```

Example: When user filled '100' in input text, it works fine in populating select box from '40' to '80', but when user changes the input text to '200' without refreshing the page, the select box show options from '40' to '80' and '01' to '05' instead of only '01' to '05'.

Expected result:  When user changes the input text to '200' without refreshing the page, the select box shows options only from '01' to '05'

Here's my working demo http://jsfiddle.net/danc32/6UqYS/1/.

Where should I put my `arr.length = 0` to reset my array?

Comment: would be helpful if u could create a working demo using jsfiddle

Comment: @iJay i did :), but here my [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danc32/6UqYS/1/) if you not seen in my post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `.append('<option>' + this + '</option>');`, every time you change you add the new options to the existing list.  Instead you could use:

```
.html('<option value="">Choose TTC First...</option>');    // remove old options
```

to reset the `select` and remove the old options, then use:

```
.append('<option>' + this + '</option>');                  // add new options
```

to add the new ones.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/TQDa3/) for complete code.

Comment: Wow! this is work fine... thanks @SuperScript .. so my problem isn't on my array then :).. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the contents of the select element before adding new items... also there is no need to recreate the `selectOptions` object within the change handler.. it is a static object so it can be created only once as given below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $priority_list = $("#priority_list").prop("disabled", true);

    var selectOptions = {};

    var arr_40_80 = arrays(40, 80);
    selectOptions['100'] = arr_40_80;
    selectOptions['101'] = arr_40_80;

    var arr_1_5 = arrays(1, 5);
    selectOptions['200'] = arr_1_5;
    selectOptions['204'] = arr_1_5;
    selectOptions['210'] = arr_1_5;

    $('input[name="ttc_list"]').change(function () {
        var ttc = $(this).val(), arr = selectOptions[ttc];

        $priority_list.prop("disabled", false).empty();
        if (arr) {
            $.each(arr, function () {
                $priority_list.append('<option>' + this + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});

function arrays(start,end){
    var arr = [];
    while (start <= end) {
        arr.push(zeroPad(start++, 2));
    }
    return arr;
}

function zeroPad(num, numZeros) {
    var n = Math.abs(num);
    var zeros = Math.max(0, numZeros - Math.floor(n).toString().length);
    var zeroString = Math.pow(10, zeros).toString().substr(1);
    if (num < 0) {
        zeroString = '-' + zeroString;
    }
    return zeroString + n;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lpvy7/)

Comment: @user2869359 that was a minor copy mistake... see the update.. it has an improved performance benefits from your code